# Team Foundation Server Integration with Sharepoint 2007 and 2010

Tags: 2010, tfs, integration, continuous-integration

I have a quick question and I cant seem to find a quick answer to it.  My company currently has a few SharePoint farms and we want to start implementing team foundation server.  I know the two softwares can interact with ease.

My questions are these.

1. Is it possible to link a new instance of team foundation server to a well seasoned SharePoint installation?  Does TFS and SharePoint need to reside on the same machine in order to interact correctly?
2. Will TFS 2013 interact with SharePoint 2010?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such limitations for TFS server with SharePoint. Please see the below points:

Here are your main points to note:

- You can use Team Foundation Server standard or advanced
  configuration wizards to install SharePoint Foundation 2013 on the
  same server as Team Foundation Server.
- The Team Foundation Server extensions for SharePoint Products are
  installed automatically during Team Foundation Server installation.
- You can use Team Foundation Server extensions for SharePoint
  Products configuration wizard to install SharePoint Foundation 2013
  on a different server from the one running Team Foundation Server.
- You can use SharePoint Server. If you use the enterprise version of
  SharePoint Server, you must configure it for dashboard compatibility
  (more on dashboard requirements later).

  You can use a different version of SharePoint Foundation than the
  one that ships with TFS.

**Supported versions, editions**

- SharePoint Foundation 2013¹ SharePoint Server 2013,¹ (Enterprise or
- Standard edition) SharePoint Foundation 2010² SharePoint Server
  2010,² (Enterprise or Standard edition)

This clearly states that Team foundation server sharepoint extensions is the key component which can connect to SharePoint with in the TFS server or external sharepoint servers. I have used both and dont see any major differences.

Please refer the below article:
    [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667648.aspx)